# Is there a way to increase the speed of multiplying $(-x^T\delta\ x )$

Tags: matrices, algorithms, symmetric-matrices, sparse-matrices

The x matrix has a size of 1024x1 and the $\delta$ has a size of 1024x1024. Delta is also a symmetric and sparse matrix. I am using the following equation to calculate a variable inside a loop.

$$x^T\delta\ x $$

Is there a faster way or a different method to this multiplication?

Comment: Faster compared to what?

Comment: Currently I am just multiplying them. So is there another way to calculate this multiplication which might reduce the computation time?